# spin glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down on mouse over as glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up

Tags: html, css

i having this glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down arrow

Customer Support

```
<a  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navLogin" href="#" style="position:relative;right:10px;" > <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" id="spn"></span></a>
```

[image: on customer support and download mobile app mouse over i want to rotate that down arrow as up how can i do it]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code? Also please edit your question, it's extremely hard to understand.

Comment: You're kidding me right?

Comment: sorry . i want the soluation this code which i use there "customer support "

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `transform` property in CSS to achieve this.

**CSS**

```
.menu-arrow {

    /* The transition, this will animate the rotation */
    transition: transform 600ms ease;
}

.menu-arrow:hover {

    /* Rotate the element 180deg on hover */
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

**Update - now that you have posted some code try this:**

**CSS**

```
#spn  {

    /* The transition, this will animate the rotation */
    transition: transform 600ms ease;
}

.dropdown-toggle:hover #spn {

    /* Rotate the element 180deg on hover */
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: <a  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navLogin" href="#" style="position:relative;right:10px;" >Customer Support&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" id="spn"></span></a>.    till its not working

Comment: change `.menu-arrow` to `#spn`

Comment: This answer was posted before you posted any code as a means of showing a sample solution. Cheers for the input Samir.